# How to create Eleventy collection in code

Tags: eleventy

I'd like to create collections based on logic other than 'tags' frontmatter:

- We use frontmatter to mark our articles with a `status`. I'd like to use this to provide collections for all the different statuses. Then I can easily show all posts 'in review' for example.
- We have a yearly review policy, so I'd like a nightly build to pick up all articles within a month of this review date and add them to another collection.

So, is there a way to programmatically create a collection in 11ty?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I must be word blind...

I've found the answer in the docs:

```js
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
  // Filter source file names using a glob
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("posts", function(collectionApi) {
    // Also accepts an array of globs!
    return collectionApi.getFilteredByGlob(["posts/*.md", "notes/*.md"]);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [article](https://www.webstoemp.com/blog/basic-custom-taxonomies-with-eleventy/) they have provided a great example of creating collection of unique categories, similar you can apply for status in your code. Please check if that helps.